# tabpage controls

Tags: c#, controls, runtime, tabpage

Is there any way to delete the controls on a tab-page that i have added on runtime ? Plz remember only to delete runtime added controls (C#) ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Are we to assume that you don't know the names of (and/or are not holding a reference to) the specific controls that you want to delete?

Comment: By default, there is no way for a control to know if it was created as part of design or runtime. You will need to mark them using Name or some other property/method. Then, iterate over all controls and delete those who are not marked.

Comment: If its a run time then wat is the need to delete them if u close your application the the controls will be availble for you any more.

if ur willing to delete the runtime Generated controls then u can use simple logic (i.e watever controls u add, while adding contrls put that control id into a variable or in Collection and later u can delete it.

Comment: thanks to all of you for your response ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add controls with unique name and delete controls whenever you want.

**Eg**:

```
 tabControl1.TabPages["tb1"].Controls.Remove("txtName");
```

**NOTE**:Control name `txtName` should be unique

Answer (score 1):

You need to either remember the name of the controls that were not added at runtime or you "flag" those that are added at runtime. E.g. by setting the TAG property with an arbitrary value. Then you can delete the controls that have a specific TAG property later.